Same verse in different qiraats
Assalamualaikum,
I am fully aware that all the ten major qiraats are authentic and have no contradictions in them. I am having trouble on ayat in particular which is Surah hud ayat 81 in hafs and Al-bazzi. I have seen one response on this website but I am still confused on how it means the same thing. In hafs the ayat reads as if the angles command prophet Lut to take everyone in his family except his wife and to not look back. On the other hand in Al-bazzi from my understanding it reads like the angles are commanding him to take everyone including his wife and that she’ll be the only one to look back. I don’t understand how the angels could have said both and meant the same thing. Jazakallah Khair for any help you can give.

Introduction
The two qira'at in this verse are to recite the word امرأتك in the nasb or the raf' cases, and each of them have their primary implications.
However, the main thing to understand is: Despite both having particular primary implications, both can be interpreted to match the other interpretation with a bit of difficulty.
It is not impossible for some recitations to be less clear or eloquent Arabic than other recitations just like some verses in the Quran can be less clear than other verses and thus one is interpreted in light of the other.
That is why those who learned one recitation preferred one interpretation and those who learned another recitation preferred another interpretation, but ultimately, neither recitations conclusively proves its view.
Let us look at each recitation, its primary interpretation, and possible ways of interpreting it differently.
The verse translation we will use is: ⟪Set out with your family at a portion of the night and no one of you should look back, except your wife. She will be struck by what strikes them.⟫
Regular Rules of Exceptions
First, we need to understand the Arabic grammar rules.
The general grammar rule in Arabic is that a normal exception is in the nasb case. However, when there is a sentence of qasr "No X except Y" the exception is in the same case as X.
In this case, there are two sentences before the exception ⟪Set out with your family⟫ and ⟪no one of you should look back⟫.
If the exception applies to the first sentence, it would be a regular exception and we expect it to be in the nasb case. If it applies to the second, it would be a qasr exception and we expect it to follow the case of أَحَدٌ (one) which is in raf'.
A note to keep in mind is that grammar rules were derived later on by grammarians, and they do not necessarily prescribe the only way words can be used. They rather describe what the grammarians found to be more common and accepted in their time after investigation.
So, it is also possible the cases were a bit more flexible in the past for exceptions. But, for the sake of this answer, let us stick to the well-known grammar rules.
Nasb Case
This is the popular recitation. It is often understood to imply that the verse means ⟪Set out with your family except your wife⟫. Meaning, Lut (AS) was told not to take his wife and thus did not take his wife.
Another possibility in the grammar is that the exception is from the sentence ⟪no one of you should look back⟫ despite the nasb.
That is because it is technically possible for qasr exceptions to have nasb even though following the case (in this case raf') is more common and preferred!
This is a very easy reconciliation in favor of the primary interpretation of the second recitation: That she was taken but she turned back.
Another possibility people gave while trying to reconcile is: Lut (AS) was told not to take his wife but his wife followed anyway.
This interpretation is plausible in itself, but it is strange if combined with the primary interpretation of the second recitation because it implies the angels told him both that he shouldn't take her and also that she would turn around. It would be fine however in some of the secondary interpretations.
Another possibility is: The verse means ⟪Set out with your family but your wife [will not be saved]⟫ where the exception is taken to be munqati'.
Munqati' is a broad term for exceptions that are not purely normal but require extra words to explain their meaning.
For example, "All the angels prostrated but Iblis [did not prostrate]" is a munqati' exception because Iblis is not an angel but the exception was given from angels because he was with them.
The purpose in giving an exception from ⟪Set out with your family⟫ could be because this command implies Allah will save their family, so an exception is given from that implication of this command.
This interpretation would fit with the primary interpretation of the second recitation that his wife did leave the city but turned around and was punished.
So, in that case, one recitation would indicate simply the fact that she would not be saved and the other recitation would indicate how she came to be punished. As for the original statement of the angels to Lut (AS) it might have been ambiguous in what they said in the same way as the Arabic is ambiguous.
Another possibility is: ⟪The angels said, "O Lot, indeed we are messengers of your Lord; [therefore], they will never reach you. So set out with your family during a portion of the night and let not any among you look back -" and the angels meant "except your wife"⟫ where the exception is understood to be an interjection by Allah to explain the intention of the angels.
This could be intended as a response to the possible question someone asks: Why did the angels tell Lut (AS) to bring his wife if she was going to be punished?
Allah answers: His wife was not included in what they said even if he misunderstood them. That is because disbelievers aren't truly family.
Allah said earlier in the same Surah to Nuh (AS) about his disbelieving son: ⟪O Noah, indeed he is not of your family⟫ (11:46)
This interpretation is what I find best, and it is supported by the fact that the Bible claims the angels said, "Take your wife and your two daughters who are here, lest you be swept away in the punishment of the city" (Genesis 19:15), so it is possible Allah wished to correct this misconception.
However, there is weakness in this interpretation due to the assumed words.
Raf' Case
This is a minority recitation. It is often understood to mean ⟪Set out with your family except your wife⟫ ⟪no one of you should look back except your wife [will look back]⟫.
The normal interpretation is that his wife came with him but turned around and was punished as a result.
This interpretation is inherently munqati' since it is not possible to take it in the regular way. It is not possible that Allah said ⟪None of you except your wife should look back⟫ because then it does not make sense for Allah to punish her when she does look back!
However, this interpretation that his wife looked back is very strong because it is confirmed by the Bible.
Other interpretations can utilize the fact that this exception is munqati' and needs an added clause by adding different more reconcilable clauses.
So, it could be ⟪no one of you should look back except your wife [do not take her at all]⟫.
Then, if you interpret the nasb as munqati' as well, it is quite easy to reconcile the two interpretations. You can simply take the assumed clause to be the same!
So, clauses like "your wife will be punished," "your wife will not be saved," or "your wife is not guaranteed safety" all can be applied to both of these munqati' exceptions instead of their primary interpretations.
Another possibility that I have not seen many people discuss but seems possible is that the word is raf' due to the lafz rather than the ma'na.
This is when a word's case is decided by its closest neighbor for the ease of pronunciation rather than the actual thing it applies to.
In this verse, the closer sentence is ⟪no one of you should look back⟫, so it is possible the word was made raf' due to this closer sentence despite actually applying to the further sentence.
Something similar is discussed in the verse of wudhu where some scholars said the word for ⟪your feet⟫ was made jarr in some recitations due to being right after another jarr word rather than what its intended meaning would lead it to be (nasb, as it is in most recitations).
This view means the original command was not to take his wife and the exception in both recitations refers to this command.
Conclusion
In conclusion, the two recitations have primary interpretations but they each can also be interpreted in other ways to fit with the primary interpretation of the other recitation or to fit a matching interpretation.
And Allah knows best.

Thank you so much for the detailed response brother. This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. One that talks about the Arabic grammar of both recitations. From all of the possibilities would you say the one where you said <That is because it is technically possible for qasr exceptions to have nasb even though following the case (in this case raf') is more common and preferred!> is the best? And do you have an example of another ayat that follows this possibility? Once again thank you so much brother for the detailed response. May Allah grant you and your family jannahtul firdoas.

@OsmanFattah It's probably one of the best, but the best is what I said. All the recitations use nasb in a qasr exception in verse 4:157.

This has been answered in previous question. Also, our great classical and contemporary scholars explained it.
To give you the recap (I am not quoting the verses but I am giving the so called contridictory reading here, so again I am not quoting the verses)
First reading is: travel with your family except your wife.
Second reading is: travel with your family, no one look back, except your wife.
Contradiction is:
1: lut (peace and blessing be upon him) travel without his wife
2. His wife travel but she looked
1st reading is a command to lut (peace and blessing he upon him) that u travel with family without your wife
2nd reading is a news/command that, when you travel don't look back but your wife will look back.
So the confusion come when ppl misunderstand the verse saying the angels commanding lut that travel with your wife. 2nd reading doesn't say that.
So it could be that his wife travel with him even tho he didn't want to take his wife and she turn back as she heard the her ppl scream.
Hance if you read ibn kathir: ibn kathir says: some scholar said she travel and some said she didn't.
And if you read imam qurtubi: he explains the meaning of 2nd reading, that command is to not look back. Command was not that "travel with your wife"
Hance no contradiction rather both reading complete and compliment each other.
If I said something wrong may Allah forgive me for my ignorance.

Jazakallah Khair  brother. May Allah bless you and your family and grant you all Jannatul firdous

Ameen. And may Allah grant you and your highest rank in jannah.
